# Early computer art - reproducing Georg Nees "Schotter" and "K27"

Tags: plotting, graphics, generative-art

Georg Nees (1926 - 2016) was a pioneer of computer art. He studied mathematics, physics and philosophy in Erlangen and Stuttgart. In 1977, he was appointed Professor of Applied computer science at the University of Erlangen, Germany.

Nees is one of the "3N" computer pioneers, an abbreviation that has become acknowledged for Frieder Nake, Georg Nees and Michael Noll, whose graphics were created with mainframe computers. Their works have been shown in countless group exhibitions worldwide.

[Victoria & Albert Museum](https://www.vam.ac.uk/exhibitions/chance-and-control-art-in-the-age-of-computers)

In 1968 Nees started his collaboration with the architect Ludwig Rase
for the Siemens Pavilion at the Hannover Industrial Fair in 1970. One
of the drawings was printed as a poster for the 35th Venice Biennale in 1970.

[image]

*Georg nees, Drawing of the Siemens Pavillion, 1970*

My favourite artwork of Georg Ness is Ellipsoide 4, created in 1986 -
two years before Mathematica saw the light of day.

[image]

*Georg Ness, Ellipsoide 4, 1986*

Nees used ALGOL to create his graphics libraries and for controlling a ZUSE Z64 flatbed drawing machine.

[image]

*ZUSE Z64*

"Schotter" (gravel), probably his best-known work, begins with a
standard row of 12 squares and gradually increases the magnitude of
randomness in the rotation and placement of the squares. The art
piece was created in 1968 on a Siemens-System 2002 and plotted with the Z64 shown above.

[image]

*Georg Nees, Schotter (gravel), 1968*

Two years earlier, in 1966, Nees produced K27:

[image]

*Georg Nees, K27, 1966*

**My question**

After almost 60 years: How many lines of Mathematica code do we need today to reproduce "Schotter" or "K27" ?

**Addendum**

Algol code of Nees' original Schotter-generator (thanks to Alex Trounev)

http://dada.compart-bremen.de/item/algorithm/1

Comment: Not sure who downvoted and why. I did the `ThumbsUp` because it's a nice question. Also, in case the person who downvoted sees this, it's more constructive to leave a comment, unless the question is obviously low-quality or spam or.... This one is not.

Comment: We expect from all users (especially newcomers) that they show their own effort and include the code in the question. This one does not – hence the downvote, as the tooltip on the button clearly says _"This question does not show any research effort;"_

Comment: @Domen Some are just too much fun to apply rules strictly.

Comment: @eldo Algol is my first language. Have you any code by Georg Nees to compare with Mathematica?

Comment: Effort can be shown by writing a detailed, documented and interesting question.

Comment: @Alex - I couldn't find any ALGOL code, but some of  Nees books are still published (expensive and in german language): [book](https://www.amazon.de/Formel-Farbe-Form-Computer%C3%A4sthetik-Medien/dp/3642633854)

Comment: @eldo In this free book on page  49 there is Algol code for Schotter“  http://www.agis.informatik.uni-bremen.de/sgrabowski/material/macSBericht2005.pdf

Comment: Please consider crossposting this to the code golf stackexchange. They'd love this.

Comment: I didn't vote (either up or down) but I see the conflict. This open-ended question asks code-golf with no clear programming hurdle to solve. Technically it's off-topic.  We are forgiving this because @eldo is a reputable contributor sharing a fun question that was well-received by most. We need to recognize that we are pleading for an exception to the rules here.

Comment: @rhermans rules are made to be broken, or at the very least bent

Comment: @bmf rules are agreements, I don't like to betray or be betrayed after we have agreed on the rules of engagement. Quoting American General Douglas MacArthur does not strengthen an exceptionalist point about our agreed set of rules, however, it does add to the irony of it. Probably we should move this conversation to [meta].

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a proposal for K27. We first create e regular grid. Then we displace randomly every point proportional to its distance from the middle.

```
rand = 3.5;
meshf[grid_] := Join[Line /@ grid, Line /@ Transpose[grid]];
nx = 10; ny = 15;
grid = Table[{x, y} + 
    rand/(1 + Norm[{x, y}])  RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2], {y, -ny, 
    ny}, {x, -nx, nx}];
mesh = meshf[grid];
Graphics[mesh, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

A quick,fun approach :

```
nx = 5; ny = 24;
Array[Rotate[
     Translate[Rectangle[{#1, -#2}, 1 + {#1, -#2}]
      , #2/ny RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2}]]
     , 10 #2/ny RandomReal[{-1, 1}] Degree] &, {nx, ny}]  //
  {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Opacity[.1]], #} & //
 Graphics
```

[image]

Comment: +1, With `nx = 12`, `EdgeForm[Gray]` and `FaceForm[Opacity[0]]` I get perfect reproductions.

Comment: a variation: `schotter[nx_, ny_] :=  Graphics[ Array[{EdgeForm[GrayLevel[(#2 + 2)/ny]], 
     FaceForm[Opacity[.9 - (#2 - 1)/ny]],    Rotate[Translate[Rectangle[{#1, -#2},   1 + {#1, -#2}], #2/ny  RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2}]],  10  #2/ny  RandomReal[{-1, 1}]  Degree]} &, {nx, ny}, 0]]; Animate[Show[schotter[12, y], PlotRange -> {{-2, 13}, {-25, 2}}, {y, 1, 24, 1}]`

Comment: Please don't use JPG for non-photographic images. JPG uses a lossy compression algorithm that (when applied reasonably) does not affect the visual appearance of a photograph noticeably. But when applied to graphs, diagrams, screenshots, images of text etc., JPG typically causes severe artefacts that are very noticeable indeed. For this kind of images (i.e., non-photographic images), PNG is a much better choice. PNG employs a lossless compression algorithm and is specifically designed for this kind of graphics.

Answer (score 10):

- For K27,maybe use `"MeshTools"` for QuadMesh.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
ResourceFunction["GitHubInstall"]["c3m-labs", "MeshTools"];
```

```
Needs["MeshTools`"];
{x,y}={3,4};
region = DiscretizeGraphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {3, 4}]];
meshTri = 
  SmoothenMesh@
   ToElementMesh[region, "MeshOrder" -> 1, MaxCellMeasure -> .05];
meshQuad = SmoothenMesh@TriangleToQuadMesh@meshTri;
reg = MeshRegion[meshQuad];
polys = MeshPrimitives[reg, MeshCellIndex[reg, {2, "Interior"}]];
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Gray], polys}]
```

[image]

- For `K27` -> `Schotter`.

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[], 
  Table[GeometricTransformation[polys[[i]], 
    RotationTransform[
      RandomReal[{0, .02}]*((y - Last@RegionCentroid[polys[[i]]])/y)]@*
     TranslationTransform[{RandomReal[{-.01, .01}], -RandomReal[{0, \
.3}]}*((y - Last@RegionCentroid[polys[[i]]])/y)^2]], {i, 1, 
    Length@polys}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**K27**, using `GridGraph`

```
SeedRandom[1];

With[{g = GridGraph[{25, 17}, VertexSize -> 0], d = 7, r = .75, c = RGBColor[.7, .7, .6]}, 
 Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> 
   MapThread[#1 -> #2 + Boole[($l = Length[FindShortestPath[g, #1, First@GraphCenter[g]]]) < d] 
      RandomReal[2 {-$l, $l}/d, 2] &
    , {VertexList@g , Map[# + RandomReal[r, 2] &, GraphEmbedding[g]]}]
, VertexStyle -> c, BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[None], EdgeStyle -> c]]
```

[image]